# resizing a picture in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

i am writing a face dection program in opencv. And this is the error code below:

```
result = img[rects[0]:rects[1], rects[2]:rects[3]] 
result = cv2.resize(result, (100,100))
```

img is our original picture and the first step is croping out our rigion of interest into result. 
The second step is resize to 100*100 pixels.

the error is:

```
result = cv2.resize(result, (100,100))
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:1725: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the size of `result` after the slicing. The slice ranges may be wrong so `result` may be an empty structure. Check also that `img` was read correctly from input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same error in python ,found that image was empty so check whether imread worked or not by using imshow or checking it for NULL then use cv2.resize .

Comment: This is true, but also if you are sure of the location and the image, try to use double backslach in the line of code where you identify the location:            ex: img=cv2.imread('C:\\user\\.....\\....\\....\\image.png')

Comment: Just in case someone made the same mistake. I got the same error because the path to the image was not complete. I forget to join the image name with the folder path.